# Visual Studio won't build project because of build path despite build path being correct?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

My Visual Studio 2019 installation won't build a Web Service I just wrote, and is saying that I have an incorrect path for WebApplications like this:

> `C:\Users\rudiejd\source\repos\CrowdRecWeb\CrowdRecWeb\CrowdRecWeb.csproj(109,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Here is the section of my .csproj where I set the MSBuild path:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild</VSToolsPath> 
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: It is a directory, not a .targets file.   The Condition clauses don't make sense either, hard to reverse-engineer why you did it this way.

Comment: Hi J.D. Rudie, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let us know if it persists to block you.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Still seems to be a problem. I am attempting to publish something with VS's default settings.  I didn't change my .csproj at all, but dotnet publish -r linux-x64 isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the problem here?

Something wrong with your csproj file. Like **Hans** commented above, you're passing a directory to `Import` element.

But in **Msbuild**, you should pass targets file(`path\xx.targets`) to `Import`  element. Simple sample like this: `<Import Project="xxx.targets"/>`. More details please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-the-same-target-in-multiple-project-files?view=vs-2019).

**Solution:**

According to your project file, the correct format should be:

```
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

After editing the project file, reload the project and rebuild it. All should work well.

**In addition:**

If you get error like `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` not found,  just make sure you've installed web development related workload:

[image]

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Yeah, so unfortunately this did not help. I definitely have the workload installed, and I'm getting the error  "C:\Users\rudiejd\source\repos\CrowdRecApi\CrowdRecApi\CrowdRecApi.csproj(268,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

Comment: I didn't change my .csproj at all, so I'm super confused as to why this is happening

Comment: It seems that there is no "VisualStudio" folder in my dotnet/sdk/3.1.100 directory. Not really sure why, since this was the default installation

Comment: Additionally, it seems that there is no WebApplications.targets at all in that folder.

Comment: Hmm, I assume your project targets .net framework instead of .net core! So you shouldn't build the project using `dotnet build command`, you should use msbuild command!

Comment: See documents about [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019), and you can find a lot of examples about how to build web projects using msbuild online.